# Kolmogorov's superposition theorem for non-continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to think about Kolmogorov's superposition theorem. This theorem states that, for each $n ≥ 2$ there exist
continuous functions $ϕ_q : [0, 1] → R, q = 0, ..., 2n$ and constants $λ_p ∈ R, p = 1, ..., n$ such
that the following statement is true: for each continuous function $f : [0, 1]^n → R$ there exists a
continuous function $g : [0, 1] → R$ such that
$$f(x_1, ..., x_n) = \sum_{q=0}^{2n} g(\sum_{p=1}^n \lambda_p \phi_q(x_p))$$

That is, any continuous function of $n$ variables can be written as a combination of sums and compositions of continuous functions of one variable.

Would a theorem like this apply if we dropped the assumption that $f$ is continuous, and the restrictions that $g,\phi_q$ be continuous?